# solve nonlinear system of equation numerically

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

solve the following system of equations numerically
$$2x+2y - e^{xy} = 0$$
$$x^3 + y - xy^3 = 1$$

I'm also asked to solve analytically but I'm pretty sure the closed form solution doesn't exist because if yes, then the second equation would involve Cardano formula, plus the log/exponential form from the top, it doesn't look closed to me.

I know if there is a solution, then it shouldn't lie in the quadrant $x<0,y<0$ because from the first equation $x+y>0$ implies either $x>0$ or $y>0$. However, I don't know how to solve completely.

thanks for any help!

Comment: After consulting WolframAlpha it seems that there is one solution pair in each of the remaining quadrants...

Comment: Copy-paste the $\LaTeX$ code into [*Desmos*](https://www.desmos.com/calculator).

Comment: actually I would like to know how to solve the problem than finding the solution for it. I know MATLAB can fsolve() with no problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a numerical method is useful to solve this system, the only way that i have in mind is to solve the second equation for $x$ or $y$ and with the first equation you got an equation in $x$ or $y$ which you can solve also by the Newton method,
i have found $$x \approx 1.059396315, y \approx -.8579048919$$

Comment: can you please explain to me how you set up an iterative Newton method? I don't see any way to substitute completely to reduce the number of variables. are you saying Newton method with 2 variables and Jacobian instead of simply first derivative?

Comment: see here a script with example http://www.unc.edu/math/Faculty/pbe/publications/Newton.pdf

Comment: oh thanks! that might be what I'm looking for. let me check!

Comment: i have send you a link

Comment: great! thank you very much for the link!

Comment: i have found three solutions of the given system